# Java-OutputStreamWriter "Spam"

Tags: java, command, spam, writer

I have built a program that sends command to another Jar(After running it). After playing around with Streams , I figured how to prevent the second Jar from crashing with every command sent. But now , another error popped up! The second jar prints Uknown Command if the command sent is not valid. After sending the command reload for example , I get feedback that the command was excecuted , but then my log wont stop printing Unknown Command !

I am sending the commands like this:

```
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(f.outputStream));
try {
    writer.write("reload");
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This is inside a thread. Then I run the thread.

Comment: Well, you haven't shown the part of your code that is behaving incorrectly... without that you're not going to get much help.

Comment: I suggest you use a `finally` block. That way you can be certain your writer is closed, even if an exception is thrown before closing it.

Comment: I have added debug messages and even if it closes , it continues to spam